# Set/Get input value using cookie

Tags: javascript, button, cookies, jquery-cookie

I want the switch button to remember selected option. Because when I refresh browser my selection is resetting..  How can I do that?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Tak" onclick="return change(this);" />
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function change( el )
    {
        if ( el.value === "Tak" ){
            el.value = "Nie";
        }else{
            el.value = "Tak";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: add cookie and update back from it.

Comment: When using jQuery I normally go with [jquery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Client side values will reset when you refresh the browser.

You need to store in `cookie` or `session` for that

Comment: Ok, but can you help me with doing that? I'm a beginer in it ;/

Answer (score 0):

Include [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to simply set and get cookie.
Something like:

```
<head>
   <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>

...
<input type="button" value="Tak" onclick="return setValue(this)" id="btn"/>
```

Now you can get/set cookie and change input value whit no problem, something like:

```
function setValue(elem){

    if(elem.value == "Tak"){
        elem.value = "Nie";
        $.cookie("btnState", true);
    } else {
        elem.value = "Tak";
        $.cookie("btnState", false);
    }
}

function getValue(){

    var c = $.cookie("btnState");

    if(c != null){

        if(c){
            $('#btn').val("Nie");
        } else {
            $('#btn').val("Tak");
        }
    } else {
        //first page view
        $.cookie("btnState", true);
        $('#btn').val("Nie");
    }

}
```

trigger `getValue()` on page load to check cookie value and set input value

**EDIT:**

To fire a function on page load use jQuery `.ready` function like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getValue();
    });
</script>
```

jQuery .ready [documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

## Here is a example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EhN9R/7/)

Comment: What do you mean with trigger getValue() because i don;t understandd.. ;/

Comment: i mean, make sure this function is fired on every page load, so it can check your cookie and set your input as needed.

Comment: The function is fired? I don't see that you use it in html code

Comment: I edited the answer, read the documentation on .ready function, you have to understand this to do anything successful in future. No point on continuing without basic knowledge! And mark answer as accepted if it answers your question.